# Get current Wallpaper android 13, more detailed problem

Tags: wallpaper, android-13

The exception happens at:

```
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

"Permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE denied" which means probably that wallpaperManager use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to work, and need to find other way to get it using `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission

Added the question (even though it is the second) because it includes more code and specifications that might help solve it.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Attached Main code, tried to change my method to include android 13, currently I see the permission window, and got stuck after that:

```
public void save_current_wallpaper_to_internal_storage() {

    //get-current-wallpaper
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {

        //READ_MEDIA_IMAGES for android 13
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES}, READ_REQUEST_CONST);
        } else {
            final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
            final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
            saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
        }
    } else {
        //READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android < 13
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_REQUEST_CONST);
        } else {
            final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
            final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
            saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CONST) {// If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wm.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
                    saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wm.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
                    saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
                }
            }
            final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wm.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
            saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);

        } else {
            Log.v("TAG", "denied");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
 Process: com.DailyWallpaper, PID: 9186
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE denied 
 for package com.DailyWallpaper
 at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
 at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
 at 
android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub$Proxy.getWallpaperWithFeature(IWallpaperManager.java:895)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:667)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:563)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:538)
at android.app.WallpaperManager.getDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:791)
at com.Daily_Wallpaper.MainActivity.save_current_wallpaper_to_internal_storage(MainActivity.java:127)
at com.Daily_Wallpaper.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda12.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.checkPermissionAndAppOp(StorageManager.java:1805)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.checkPermissionAndAppOp(StorageManager.java:1782)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.checkPermissionAndAppOp(StorageManager.java:1849)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.checkExternalStoragePermissionAndAppOp(StorageManager.java:1965)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.checkPermissionReadImages(StorageManager.java:1931)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue.
See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237124750 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236690156

No acceptabe solution by far.