Android wont request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission
I am trying to get the phones wallpaper like so:
val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
val wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.drawable

But am getting an error that I need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
In my manifest I have the following:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

And in my activitys onCreate method I am calling this:
    fun isStoragePermissionGranted(): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted")
                true
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked")
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf<String>(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                    1
                )
                false
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted")
            true
        }
    }

Initially I had tried just requesting android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, which was doing nothing, so as a test I added android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA. The app DID request the camera permission when I added it, but it never requests READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
What am I missing?

Please read the documentation. It states that this permission is ignored on devices with Android 13+ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

@Robert so how do i get my app to stop crashing with the error stating that "app is missing READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Guess it is not possible... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027193/get-current-wallpaper-android-13-more-detailed-problem

If you don't plan to release the app on Google Play you can use permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

@Robert as it says in my post, I already have that permission, it doesn't work

You have declared it but have you activated it for the app? That permission has to be manually activated in Android settings, if can not be requested by the app itself.

@Robert yes, I have gone to the settings and given all file access to the app, it still didnt work
